# Pipe program output to rsyslog

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have a process running that writes it's output to a file, like this.

```
processx > /var/log/processx.log 2>&1
```

How would I write/pipe/forward this to rsyslog instead (including the `2>&1` redirect)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either pipe it to logger `processx | logger (and the options you want)` or use the [Text File Input Module](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/imfile.html) for rsyslog to read your existing file.

Comment: Updated my question slightly (`2>&1`).

Comment: `processx 2>&1 | logger ...`